# UI Freeze while working on ui layer

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, freeze

I have an application, in which`UIViewController` hangs or freezes while  performing layer operation on `UIView`

I have written my code like this

```
viewLayer.cornerRadius = 8;
[viewLayer setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[viewLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
[viewLayer setShadowOpacity:1];
[viewLayer setShadowRadius:2.0];
```

This code is written in `viewDidLoad` method, so its hangs the animation while navigating to this viewController

Comment: Put in inside the init method instead.

Comment: I tried it.. nothing happen

Comment: If you're initing from a xib it wouldn't as the viewlayer probably doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @nickfalk so what should I do next

Comment: Are you sure the delay is actually happening due to this code or are you perhaps experiencing delays due to the view being initialized?

Comment: Put this in viewDidappear, your view will be prepared by then and would be ready for these UI changes.

Comment: yes, when I comment this code of lines, All is well

Comment: @RenoJones Thanks for giving me valuable comment, I tried it, and got success.

Comment: That's the beauty of it :) Cheers.